# Add "Start of text (Hex 02)" and "End of text (Hex 03)" to a message string using Perl

Tags: perl

Using Perl, I'm trying to add "Start of text (Hex 02)" and "End of text (Hex 03)" to a message string example below:

```
my $hex02 = 0x02;                               
my $hex03 = 0x03;                                 
my $hex02_ascii = sprintf "%c", $hex02;          
my $hex03_ascii = sprintf "%c", $hex03;         
$Message = $hex02_ascii.$Message.$hex03_ascii;
```

Results are not correct, getting `"?datastring?" ?=Hex 3F` for Start and End of text...
What I'm trying to achieve is " datastring " (Within double quotes are 0x02,datastring,0x03)
Example:

```
STX - 1 byte (0x02)
Payload - datastring
ETX - 1 byte (0x03)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you checking the result? Include the code.

Comment: It works for me. Also, it's easier with `$Message = "\x02$Message\x03";`.

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted does what you want.

```
$ perl -e'
   use v5.14;
   use warnings;

   my $Message = "datastring";

   my $hex02 = 0x02;
   my $hex03 = 0x03;
   my $hex02_ascii = sprintf "%c", $hex02;
   my $hex03_ascii = sprintf "%c", $hex03;
   $Message = $hex02_ascii.$Message.$hex03_ascii;

   say sprintf "%v02X", $Message;
'
02.64.61.74.61.73.74.72.69.6E.67.03
```

You could also print out `$Message` and pipe the output to `hexdump -C`.

```
$ perl -e'
   ...
   print $Message;
' | hexdump -C
00000000  02 64 61 74 61 73 74 72  69 6e 67 03              |.datastring.|
0000000c
```

Without `hexdump -C` or similar, you can't really tell what output you got because 02 and 03 are not printable characters. Your terminal might *display* them as `?`. But that doesn't mean they are `?` (3F).

---

That said, it can be written a lot simpler.

```perl
$Message = "\x02$Message\x03";
```

Comment: That is much simpler but I'm still getting the same results... hex 3F and not hex 02 at the start of string followed by hex 3F and not hex 03 at end of string.

Comment: I don't know why you claim that, but you are wrong. It's simply impossible for `sprintf "%c", 0x02` and `"\x02"` to produce anything but a character with a value 2. I suggested one possible reason you might *think* otherwise. In any case, repeating a false claim isn't going to help. If you want to move forward, you need to provide a demonstration of your problem, something you have yet to provide.

Comment: Understand your reasoning, that's why I'm in misbelief but it a matter fact that Hex 3F is, for whatever reason, is the end result of using the recommended solution. It's not just me seeing the results in debug mode but the message stream is rejected when sent to server expecting proper "Start of text (Hex 02)" and "End of text (Hex 03)" on the received message string. Well documented TCP/IP expected on transmitted messages.

Comment: You know how to check what string is produced, yet you keep making false claims. You know you have to do to move forward, yet you keep spamming instead.